# Why is a corner of our garage floor slab all uneven?

Tags: concrete, garage, foundation, slab

Our house was built ~1985, and it has quite a few oddities. One of them is an irregularly shaped corner of our garage. Our garage is ~32' (9.75m) x 32' (9.75m), and a significant section (not square ~12' (3.75m) squared) in the back corner is different, uneven and bad.

Are there any rational reasons for this/reasons why it would be a bad idea to try and fix it? It looks like it has expansion joints between the squares.

Here's a shot of the weirdly shaped uneven section:
[image: Corner of garage]

The other direction:
[image: Other side of the garage]

A close up shot of a representative square:
[image: Example squares of concrete]

Why this is such a pain in the butt:
[image: Difference in height between squares]

Comment: looks like there was a wooden patio there ... judging from the embedded patio slabs, the concrete is probably around 2" thick ... i would just break one of the embedded slabs just to see what's underneath

Comment: There are several possible causes one being it was a DIY poured by hand in small batches , possible repair work where the slab was cut and a really crappy replacement since the main slab looks good. I would remove the bad pour and replace for best results since the existing work is questionable.